# How to get rid of empty lines in the middle of the text file while reading in c?

Tags: c, text-files

I have created a .c program that when it runs it is supposed to read, print and store lines that are not empty and ignore the blank/empty lines. However, when I tried using my program, it read the blank line as 0 and random numbers and messes up my algorithm. I am currently running this on ubuntu in c.

The text file contains

```
0 20
10 200
12 150
21 230

26 75
```

The main code is :

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

/* ------------------------------------ Read textfile ------------------------------------ */ 

char filename; / second input will be filename */ filename = argv[1]; FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");


/* if amount of input less than or more than 2, prompt the input format*/ 
if (argc != 2){
    printf("\nPlease enter in this format : ./assignment <text-file-name.txt>\n");
}

/* Check for errors.
 Use perror("") or strerror(errno) for more meaningful error messages */
if (!fp) {
    printf("\nError opening \"%s\": %s.\n\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
} else {
    printf("\nSuccesfully Open!\n\n");
} 

int numofProcesses = 0;

/* reading line by line, max 256 bytes */
const unsigned MAX_LENGTH = 256;
char SingleLine[MAX_LENGTH];
float arrival[100], burst[100];

while (fgets(SingleLine, MAX_LENGTH, fp) != NULL)
{
    /* Remove trailing new line */
    size_t newline_pos = strcspn(SingleLine, "\n");
    SingleLine[newline_pos] = 0;
    
    /* Parse the line read */
    if (sscanf(SingleLine, "%f %f", &arrival[numofProcesses], &burst[numofProcesses]) != 2) {
        printf ("Error in the textfile");
    }
    numofProcesses = numofProcesses + 1;
}
fclose(fp);

/* Print to check number of procesess, arrival time and burst time */
printf("Number of Processes: %d\n", numofProcesses);
for (int i = 0; i < numofProcesses; i++)
    printf("%.2f %.2f\n", arrival[i], burst[i]);
}
```

The output I get is :

```
Number of processes : 6
0.00 20.00
10.00 200.00
12.00 150.00
21.00 230.00
random numbers 0.00
26.00 75.00
```

But the output I am expecting is :

```
0.00 20.00
10.00 200.00
12.00 150.00
21.00 230.00
26.00 75.00
```

Is it possible to achieve that? May I know if there is any suggestion on this issue? Thank you.

Comment: `if(strlen(SingleLine)) == 0) continue;`

Comment: After `printf ("Error in the textfile");` add `continue;`